# What to do after being exposed to someone with the flu/cold

Tags: infection, common-cold, prevention, influenza, disinfection

If I spent 45 minutes in a car with closed windows with someone that had a cold/flu, what would I have to do immediately after exiting the vehicle to reduce and if possible eliminate the chance of getting infected?

Comment: Get a custom-built inhaler medicine that removes or blocks sialic acid receptors on the respiratory epithelium (reference: https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC4592815/). This should hinder the spread somewhat.